# How to disable resizing and reordering of columns in NSTableView

Tags: swift, macos, swift3, nstableview

I am using NSTableView in an OS X app, using Swift 3. I am not able to figure out how to disable reizing of columns and also reordering of columns

Comment: I don't understand why I am getting downvoted :| Any reasons? I did search and I couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: most likely why is because you are not giving enough information in your question. Take a look at this article here to help you get an idea of how to structure your answer - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can literally google the title of this question, and the third hit is an Apple developer page which has the answer.

Comment: You don't provide sufficient information.  We don't know whether you are trying to do it programmatically or through the interface builder.

Comment: @Ssswift I can't see here :| I did literally google the title - http://i.imgur.com/9WTHRZ4.png I would appreciate if you can give me the link

Comment: Did you check the properties of the table view and columns in IB (Xcode) and in the documentation?

Comment: @Willeke figured out how. Earlier I was checking in XCode's documentation and I didn't know why it was not showing. But I found it on web version - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer on [official docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview) :

```
tableView.allowsColumnResizing = false
tableView.allowsColumnReordering = false
```